# Cite chapter from reference in definition

Tags: citing, theorems

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{paper}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[subsection]

\begin{document}

\begin{defn}[\cite[III.1]{sil}]
Let $E$ 
\end{defn}

\end{document}
```

The point is that this throws an error, but if I remove the brackets surrounding `\cite` it works fine. Any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: @Mico Thanks, `\protect` worked. What's `\protect` btw? First time seeing it. If you can write an answer, I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose the `\cite[..]{..}` command in extra brackets `{...}`, otherwise the `]` in the cite command gets interpreted as the closing square bracket for the optional argument of the `defn`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{paper}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[subsection]

\begin{document}

\begin{defn}[{\cite[III.1]{book-minimal}}]
Let $E$
\end{defn}

\bibliographystyle{amsplain}
\bibliography{xampl}

\end{document}
```

`\protect` does *not* help here, it is not a question of a moving argument.